# Accessing Static Method and Static bool in other class

Tags: c++, static

I have a base interface class:

```
class A
{
public:
    ITask(){}
    virtual bool Start()=0;
    virtual void Update()=0;
    virtual void Stop()=0;
};
```

I now have 2 other classes, that inherit from this

```
#include "A.h"
#include "C.h"
class B: public A
{
public:
    bool Start(){} 
    void Update()
    {
        c.Start();
    } 
    void Stop(){}

    static bool m_run;

    static void SetRun(bool run)
    {
        m_run = run;
    }
private:
    C c;
};
```

lastly I have a 3rd class:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
class C : public A
{
public:
    bool Start()
    {
        B::SetRun(false); // cant do this
        B::m_run = false; // or this
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void Stop()
    {

    }
}
```

I have shaved down some of the code, for simplicity.

I dont understand why I cant access the static var in B. Do I need to make it a pointer or a ref?

I get 2 errors:

```
error C2653: 'B' : is not a class or namespace name
error C3861: 'm_run': identifier not found
```

Comment: No-repo after fixing some typo and other minor mistakes. http://ideone.com/7RTdJ. Please show the actual code.

Comment: It does not look like these are your complete files, because `B.h` is missing an include of `A.h`, and the capitalization of `SetRun` is different between `B.h` and `C.h`. Could you please update the question with your actual files that we could copy-paste into files and try to compile locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you don't show it, I'm assuming that `B.h` includes `C.h`; otherwise the line `C c;` won't compile. This causes a circular dependency in the header files: `B.h` must be included before `C.h`, which must be included before `B.h`, which is impossible.

The easiest solution is to move the body of `C::Start` out of the definition of `C`, so that `C.h` does not need to include `B.h`. The function definition can go into a source file, or a separate header if you want to keep it inline.

Alternatively, you could modify `B` to contain a `std::unique_ptr<C>` rather than an instance of `C`, and implement a constructor (in a source file, or a separate header) that initialises it with `new C`. Then `B.h` only needs to forward declare `class C;` rather than including `C.h`.

A better solution, if possible, would be to rethink the relationships between the classes so that there isn't a circular dependency.

(UPDATE: while I was writing this answer, the question changed to show that `B.h` does indeed include `C.h` as I guessed.)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your example code (after the edits), the problem must be somewhere else, like a failed include.

Comment: I think it might be do do with the private var C c in B.h

Comment: Obviously, you can't declare c in B.h, because class C is not known at that point, but that is a different compiler error

Comment: If you made the right include for C c, then that could explain the failed include, so B is not known (mutual dependency)

Comment: Just made an edit in class B (include C.h) is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, now it is clear: 2 header files can't include each other. This can be fixed by defining C::Start in a source file

Comment: Or fixing your design to avoid this construction